# Objective C - IOS - Xcode 4.6.2 - can't hear sound from mp3 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.6

I'm following in a tutorial on how to play mp3 sounds when pressing a button.

I created a button (playSound).

I added it to the view controller interface:

```
- (IBACTION)playSound:(id)sender;
```

in the implementation I declared the needed header files and I wrote the following:

```
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVfoundation.h"

- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {

    //NSLog(@"this button works");
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"];
    //NSLog(@"%@", audioPath);
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
    //NSLog(@"%@", audioURL);
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    [audioPlayer play];

}
```

I'm not getting any errors. the NSlogs are logging the URL fine, and now I have no clue where to look further. I also checked if my MP3 sound was maybe damaged, but that was also not the case. all i hear is a little crackling noise for 1 second. then it stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a local variable `audioPlayer` to hold a pointer to the player. As soon as your button handler returns **the player is being released before it has a chance to play your sound file.** Declare a property and use it instead of the local variable.

In YourViewController.m file

```
@interface YourViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@end
```

or in YourViewController.h file

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@end
```

Then replace `audioPlayer` with `self.audioPlayer` in your code.

Comment: This fixed it! this was quite a problem. Thanks a lot! and thanks everyone who tried to give me a hand :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your audio file" 
                                                              ofType:@"type of your audio file example: mp3"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Try this and let me know.  **Make sure you set the delegate for audioPlayer.**

Comment: This also didnt work for me. Could you explain what your way of thinking was with adding     audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;    to the code?

Comment: Yes it does. I checked if the file was damaged or not. It's working completely fine. - URL: file://localhost/Users/kevinvanhengst/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/CF8BC92D-AEEE-4185-96F5-650572A3BFC1/WillemsKantineSoundboard.app/audio.mp3

Comment: I checked if the file was added in the "Copy Bundle Resources" and it was there as well. I'm kinda lost..

Comment: Have set delegate for Audio Player?

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me

in .h

```
AVAudioPlayer * _backgroundMusicPlayer;
```

in .m

```
NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Theme" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];
    NSError *error;
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly re add your music file in your project , then try this code
With the log you can see error.

```
NSError *error;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg_sound" ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer   *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                              initWithContentsOfURL:url
                              error:&error];
if (error){
//Print Error
NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
[audioPlayer play];
audioPlayer.volume=1.0;

}
```

**Make sure your music files are properly added in project**

Comment: I get the exact same result as with my code. I hear some crackling for 1 second, and that's it. Could it be possible that it is something with my software? Is my code working for you?

Comment: Yes this code is working for me, have you tried it on device.
What is the length of your audio play back, you can test your code with some other audio file.

Comment: im using a quite big audio file atm. around 6mb. But after testing with a 4kb sound file there is no difference.

Comment: did that a few times already. It would be funny if that solved the problem. doing to try and deploy it on a real device, and see what it does then. If the code is working on your machine, and not on mine, it's obviously a software issue. Thx for assisnting me! :)